# Is there way to confirm user email when user change his email - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have an option that allows a user to change email in his profile but without confirming a new email so when he enters a new email I want activate the email to save it in his profile, how to add confirm

- I am using UserCreationForm

models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

my code | forms.py :

```
# Profile Form
class EmailChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True,label='Email',widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control center container','style': 'width:85%;text-align: center;background-color:#f6f6f6','placeholder':' Enter Your New E-mail '}) )
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            'email',
            ]
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count():          raise forms.ValidationError('Email is already in use, please check the email or use another email')
        return email
```

views.py :

```
# Edit Profile View
class EmailChange(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = EmailChangeForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
    template_name = 'user/commons/EmailChange.html'
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return self.request.user
```

urls.py :

```
from django.urls import path
from blog_app.views import SignUpView, ProfileView, ActivateAccount,EmailChange

urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/change-email/me/', EmailChange.as_view(), name='emailchange'),
]
```

html page :

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" style="background-color:#7952b3" value=" change ">
</form>
```

what is the next step will be to add activation when the user adds a new email?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough idea for email activation. First you need to setup the your mail server/smtp server. Then add a new field in your model for hash which will be generated while changing the email. When user changes his/her email, show persistent message to send confirmation email to his email account, you can use django's message framework to do that. After clicking on sending the email, you can show message to make the user confirm the email and activate the account. Then make a function in views.py and also a url route to validate the hash and activate the account. The url that was sent in the email to the user will contain the route you created for activation with the hash which was generated while email was changed. You can use your existing Boolean field to check if the email was validated or not.